# jScrollPane scrolling down when dragging down a listitem

Tags: jquery, drag-and-drop, scroll, jscrollpane

when using the current version of jScrollPane.

The scrollpane will not scroll down when someone drags down an item in the sortable list 
located in the scrollpane.

When i use an older version of jScrollpane ([jSrollPane.js 93 
2010-06-01 08:17:28Z kelvin.luck](http://www.kelvinluck.com/assets/jquery/jScrollPane/sortables.html)) 
scrolling when dragging works perfectly, but the old version does not 
support a lot of options i essentially need!

How do i get the newer version of jScrollPane to scroll down on dragging down?

I've searched through nearly everything ...

thanks for any help, 
haemse

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That isn't currently supported in jScrollPane 2. There is an open ticket for it:

https://github.com/vitch/jScrollPane/issues#issue/4

If you want to try and implement it then the relevant place to look from jScrollPane 1 is in the `onSelectScrollMouseDown` function and the functions it calls...